Connecting to a nats server with PHP
I have my nats server running in a docker container, I'm writing a php script that connects to the server and publishes a message but I'm new to php
So I wanted to ask is this similar to connecting to a database? if not please can anyone provide me with some tutorials or something. Thank you!
EDIT: I'm using repejota/phpnats as a library

Are you using one of these PHP libraries or are you writing your own? Anyway, those libraries have some documentation and make it easier to get started.

On the offical download page there is a link to a couple of php clients:
https://nats.io/download/#clients
